# Validate data when using out of the box dialog available with Setup and Deployment Projects

Tags: setup-project, setup-deployment

How to validate data when using the out-of-the-box dialogs provided by the visual studio setup and deployment project?

I have added a dialog (using 'Add Dialog') in the start phase of the normal install. The dialog consists of three text boxes to get the data to form a connection string that will be required for connecting to the database. I want to validate the data before user proceeds with the installation. I could not find a way of doing it? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually validation is performed through UI custom actions. To run a custom action when a button is pressed (for example the "Next" dialog button), you can use DoAction control events.

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu: Can that be done using the setup and deployment wizard?

Comment: Not really. I recommend using a free or commercial setup authoring tool.